# file upload taking longer for user than me

Tags: php, windows-7, file-upload, performance

I have a really odd problem and i'm running out of ideas of what might be the cause.

I have a page on my site which allows users to upload photos to the website. I have a particular user who says its taking around 2 minutes to upload a photo. However, when he uploads the same photo onto flickr, it takes about 20 seconds. He has provided me with the photo, I have logged into his account and used the same web browser and found that it only takes around 20 seconds for myself to upload the same file!

He is running IE9, Windows 7 64bit, decent spec computer and he's not on the other side of the world. We are both roughly the same distance from the server.

Any ideas what might be the problem or other things I should check?

Comment: How large is the photo? Both in terms of file size, and dimensions? What are his internet connection's specs, and what are yours?

Comment: Filesize: 1.7 MB, Dimensions: 2871 x 1876 (72 dpi). I'll check his internet speed. I get on average 4MB down, 2MB up.

Comment: Firstly check his net connection.
Secondly, check whether he is trying to connect the server via any kind of proxy or not.
(Btw did you check that its taking really '2 mins' from his system? If not check this also by urself. :))

Comment: His connection is 10MB down, .5mb up. I can't really check on his system for him as he's miles away from me, but hes roughly the same distance from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can also be a product of routing. If his isp doesn't have a peering agreement with your website host, the traffic can take some bottlenecked route. You can have the user try a traceroute against your host, and see if anything weird pops up. ISPs control the outgoing route, so that's why the user can download from your site with proper speeds, while the other way can go slow.